# cmake and external library

Tags: c++, cmake

I try to use cmake with an external library but  i can't. I use minGW and g++ compiler.
My project is organised as follow:
project/

- CMakeLists.txt
- src

  - main.cpp
- lib

  - win

    - x86

      - SDL2-2.0.3 (contains SDL2.dll, SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib and SDL2test.lib
- include

  - SDL2 (contains all header)
- bin

The cmake generator works `cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"

My cmake file:
`

```
    #
    # File generated by CMakeBuilder
#
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT ( project CXX )


################ INCLUDE Libs ####################

SET (CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/")
SET (CMAKE_LINKER_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/win/x86/SDL2-2.0.3/")

message(STATUS "INCLUDE_PATH: ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH}" )
message(STATUS "LINKER_PATH: ${CMAKE_LINKER_PATH}" )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_LINKER_PATH})

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lmingw32 ")

#Generate file source

file( GLOB_RECURSE  source_files  src/*)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(project ${source_files})
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})
```

But when i launch make, i obtain this error:

`

```
CMakeFiles/project.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple
     definition of main
        C:/Users/Gege/workspaces/workspaceCPP/project/lib/win/x86/SDL2-2.0.3/SDL2m
        ain.lib(./Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main]+0x0): first defined here
        Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
        C:/Users/Gege/workspaces/workspaceCPP/project/lib/win/x86/SDL2-2.0.3/SDL2m
        ain.lib(./Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[_main]+0x12): undefined reference
     to SDL_main'
        c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:               C:/Users/Gege/workspaces/workspaceCPP/project/lib/win/x86/SDL2-    2.0.3/SDL2main.lib(./
        Release/SDL_windows_main.obj): bad reloc address 0x8 in section .text[_WinMain@
        16]'
        collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        CMakeFiles/project.dir/build.make:87: recipe for target 'bin/project.exe'
        failed
        make[2]: *** [bin/project.exe] Error 1
        CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/project.dir/all'           faile
        d
        make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/arduinoGeo.dir/all] Error 2
        Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
        make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`
Actually i don't want to put my lib in minGW folder to keep the build easy for the others.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Those errors don't appear to result from any problem with CMake. Have you compared the build steps generated by CMake to build steps you can run by hand to get the correct output? Are you using the correct SDL2 binaries (e.g., mingw vs. visual studio binaries)?

Comment: Actualy it's the way to add library, in cmakefile the library must be added like this:


set(library_link_sdl mingw32 SDL2main SDL2 ) and it's works. Thanks you